# how to find vertex of Images (mountain)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Am new to andengine. I am developing a game which contain mountain , so I want to find vertex of that mountain which repeating continuously.I want to find collision of sprite with mountain.I tried but trite  mountain as a rectangle so sprite collide with mountain rectangle not  exact mountain.

```
TextureRegion mountainRegion=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                gameObjectsAtlas, activity.getAssets(), "mountain.png");
```

My mountain like 
[image]

Comment: Show us what you have up to now and where exactly it is failing.

Comment: I am developing game like a flappy bird so my main game spite move from mountain so. I did all code but main problem is maintain images react as a rectangle.I want to collision on exact mountain body.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this be an external tool , There are few tools that you can read about:

Vertex Helper , and Physics Editor.

I'm recommending on Physics Editor
in this tool you load you image , and its export the shape into a XML , than you can load it in the andengine and it will collide in the proper why

You can read more and Download it here:

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/features